# Question about Boolean rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, boolean-ring, ring-isomorphism

As we know every finite boolean ring in which $1≠0$ is isomorphic to, $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

So, is every infinite boolean ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \cdots\ $(infinite copies)?

Answer (score 3):

No.  For instance, if $I$ is any set, then any subring of the product $\mathbb{Z}_2^I$ will also be a Boolean ring, and such subrings usually are not themselves products of copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  For instance, any infinite product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ must be uncountable, but you can take the subring of $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\mathbb{N}}$ generated by a countably infinite subset to get a subring which is countably infinite.  Such a subring cannot be isomorphic to any product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, since it is infinite but not uncountable.

However, every Boolean ring has this form: every Boolean ring is isomorphic to a subring of $\mathbb{Z}_2^I$ for some set $I$.  This is a somewhat hard theorem (a weak form of [Stone's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras)).

Answer (score 2):

No, there are many infinite Boolean algebras (equivalent to a Boolean ring), not only the powers of $\{0,1\}$. E.g the Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can give some example of infinite boolean  rings which are not isomorphic to $Z_2 × Z_2 ×...$

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi I gave one. Also the regular open sets of the reals etc. or the cofinite algebra on  a countable set.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the Boolean algebra corresponding to a ring of the form $\prod_{i\in I}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ will have *atoms* - that is, nonzero elements which don't properly bound any nonzero elements (think about the element corresponding to $\delta_i$ for $i\in I$ ...). So any atomless Boolean algebra will yield a Boolean ring which is not of that form.